# What to do if nothing to return. Java

Tags: java, exception, return

There is `long get(int key)` method in my container class.

What to do if i have no matches for `key` value?

Throw an exception? Something else?

Comment: Change it to `Long` and return `null`. Change it to `OptionalLong` and return an empty value. Return a `long` value that signal absence, like `-1`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Good suggestions. I would avoid returning a `null` though. That causes client code to be a little more prone to runtime failure.

Comment: you can just put an info log about no value found or return an empty object. One should throw an exception only if you don't want to deal with the situation.

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest to throw an exception, which clearly describe your method from its signature. I will not suggest to returning null or returning -1 if no match found, because the behavior of the method will not be reflected from its signature. Who ever is going to use that method need to remember or somewhere you need to document that if no matching found then it will return null or -1 and in the client code they need to handle it with condition. But by throwing exception you are documenting the behavior in the method signature itself. And in the client code they have to handle as the method throws exception.

Comment: +1 Exceptions are a powerful tool for conveying inability to return the normal form of result. They give the caller a lot of options for how to handle it. If you use a checked exception, there is no risk of just ignoring the condition until it causes another problem, as would be the case for -1 or null.

Comment: If to choose exception, what kind of exception i should throw?
`throw new Exception("No matches for the key")` will be ok, or i need to define my own exception?

Comment: Create your own. IllegalArgumentException would fit the bill, but it's a RuntimeException and so not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to handle that in your container class. Handle it in the controller class or the class that calls that method. If you really want to, if nothing comes back, just return -1. **EDIT:** If -1 is a valid value, then pick a value that is not a valid value to be a return value. My preference is to avoid NULL.

Example.

```
if ( get(tempKey) == -1 )
    //you know it isn't a match, do something with it, throw exception...etc.
```

Comment: What if `-1` is a valid return value?

Comment: What if `-1` is a valid value?

Comment: If his method can return -1 then this will not work.  Also he was asking what to do if a value did not match, not how to detect if the value did not match.

Answer (score 1):

You should do whatever suits the use cases of your container:

1. If calling your container with an absent index is probably an error
   in the calling client code, then you should throw an exception.
2. If calling this method with an absent key is quite usual and does not
   signify the error, then probably client code expects some default
   value in absence of an explicitly set value. So you should return
   this value.
3. If you want to explicitly state that there is no value
   for this key, and expect the client code to handle this correctly,
   then change the return type to Long and return null.

In any case, write good documentation for your container class and method that clearly defines its contract.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what it can return.  If it can never return -1 then you can return -1 (this is often used for this sort of thing).

If it can return -1 then you can throw an exception.

You can also use the [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) class to return null, but throwing an exception should be better.

Comment: I don't like the option of throwing an exception as it will lead to the exception being used for flow control which is a big code-smell.

Comment: @PhilAnderson Then they can use a Long and return null.

Comment: Yep. That's certainly an option

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the application - is what I would say. I will try to ensure both of your queries in the posting above.

I would return **Long.MIN_VALUE** for your first query and **null** for your second query.

Returning `null` is not all that bad - read below for an explanation for my choices.

As a rule of thumb whenever you are developing your classes and methods that invoke other classes and methods; you should define the expected contracts (parameters and return values) based upon the way your logic would process them after having invoked the method.

In you case, if the method must return a **long** and you do not have anything to return then return Long.MIN_VALUE. This way you insulate the application from cases where negative numbers would be valid return values - it is rare to have a program that processes Long.MIN_VALUE.

Coming to the second question - what should be returned when a key is not present within a map. Well the Java SDK shows the way :  Returning null would be your best bet. This would force you to check for valid return values from the get() method before processing your code. Assuming that you do not catch NullPointerException this would also result in your application definitely crashing in case you miss such checks - a good fail-fast implementation that would help you identify the missing links.